# Icon grid that overlay when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, icon

I'm looking for something that works like this:

The page is a 4x4 grid of icons (boxes with small pictures and a title).  When someone clicks on one of them, an overlay gracefully is displayed with more info on that topic.  The user then clicks an X in the upper-right corner or whatever to close.

I don't want a popup in the sense of opening a new web page.

Anyone seen something like this?  Ideally, a jQuery or javascript component I can just plugin without having to write a bunch of code...looked around on CodeCanyon, etc. but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

These are generally referred to as "modals" and there are numerous available libraries.

If using jQuery, you could look at [jQuery-ui's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) (which I personally hate but seems to be popular), or just roll your own. There's plenty of options available out there.